# SQL - Prior 3 year date

Tags: sql, sql-server

Could someone please assist me for a simple SQL code. I have a table with the following fields: Id, item, processed_date. How do I pull data from this table prior three years from a certain date in the processed_date field?
for example
i like to know how many items that were sold on 12/6/05 but three years prior to that date?

Thanks very much
Joe

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: what RDBMS?  date math varies

Comment: hi i am using SQL server

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are in sql-server, use `datediff()` method:

```
select * from mytable where  DATEDIFF(year,'2012-06-05',processed_date field)>3
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking to get stuff on a certain date and 3 years prior to that date?

```
Select *
from myTable
where processed_date < DATEADD(YEAR, -3,  processed_date)
```

Comment: @ Bryan, i am trying to get the stuff 3 years prior to that date (12/6/15).